# query for viewing all posts by some user or posts having any specific value

Tags: support, stack-overflow, data-explorer, posts

On data.stackexchange I am unable to get any results(rows) from following quries

```
select Top 10 * from Posts where OwnerDisplayName = 'Rodolphe';
select * from Posts where OwnerUserId=992165; // My user id
select * from Posts where OwnerUserId=603393; // Rodolphe id
```

The query which is giving results(rows)

```
select Top 10 * from Posts order by CreationDate desc;
```

But even the last query giving latest results of 2012-06-27 which is not understandable for me

Does data.stackexchange only show the posts or user of it and not the stackoverflow?

If thats the case how can i find the posts on stackoverflow of my specific interest

Comment: Given that this is programming related, might this be better on SO proper, or are such questions fine here?

Comment: @Bart: he just asked if he could ask this here, and the answer was positive. :-)

Comment: Hahaha, okay, I was unaware of that. And here I was tempted to vote to close... :) Top tip: don't listen to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data dump used for data.stackexchange.com is updated once every few months. The last update was on June 27th (as [listed on the data-explorer homepage](https://data.stackexchange.com/)).

You were not active on Stack Overflow until July 16th, and thus don't have anything listed in the Posts table. You *are* listed in the Users table though.

Note that for me, the `select * from Posts where OwnerUserId=603393` query does return results. The `where OwnerDisplayName` probably just times out, that column is not indexed (I suspect) and thus a complete table scan would be needed to find matching rows.

Comment: "The data dump used for data.stackexchange.com only includes active users..." Citation?

Comment: @WaffelizedBobby: The OP has been a member of SO for 10 months but isn't in the data dump; his activity tab the user wasn't active until July. It's just a correlation of facts, no external references used. :-) In other words, I strongly *suspect* this is the case.

Comment: May be 603393 had not posted anything before 27th june, Otherwise i think its simple query, should give results. Thanks for the accurate/clear reasoning and answer.

Comment: Interesting, I always assumed that *everything* gets dumped.

Comment: @WaffelizedBobby: Actually, my assumption was wrong. There were no *posts* for that user, but the user *is* present in the Users table.